# How can I draw each parts of the pressure vessel bottom plate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I was working on the pressure vessels and it was difficult for me to draw the parts of the **bottom plate**. Why are the bottom plate designed to overlap the plates each other? The picture is below

[image]

Comment: You haven't even bothered to proofread the title.  Disrespecting the volunteers here you seek a favor from is not a good way to get free help.

Comment: If you don't know why, you have no business designing pressure vessels.

Answer (score 2):

They overlap to avoid butt joints.